# How to get the following matrix out of two vectors in pythonic way?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have two vectors **a** and **b** and I need to construct a matrix like this:

[image]

A solution that should work would be to stack the **a** ector three times and then do an element-wise multiplication.

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
b = numpa.array([10,20,30])
c = numpy.vstack((a,a,a)) * b
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Look into `np.multiply.outer`.

Comment: if a , b are same size why cant you just go with a*b?

Comment: `a_3b_3` in position `row=1`, `col=2` seems odd...

Comment: Yes sorry, there should be b_2 everywhere in row 2.

Comment: The outer product was what I was looking for. Could you please turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can matrix-multiply a-transpose with b:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([1, 2, 3])
b = np.matrix([10, 20, 30])
a.T * b
```

With only arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([10, 20, 30])
np.multiply.outer(a, b)      # thanks to @Divakar in the comments
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works. I would like to restrict my program to use strictly arrays instead of matrices, though. (Yes retyping is not difficult). It is just for program clarity.

Comment: ok, then you can use @Divakar suggestion in the comments: I updated my answer adding `np.multiply.outer` of numpy arrays.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks :)